# Usuário root mysql sem permissão

Tags: mysql, linux

Estou tendo um problema pra alterar permissões de usuários no mysql com o usuário root, no Debian.

Consigo acesso normalmente pelo terminal:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Assim ele me solicita a senha do root, coloco a senha e acesso normal. Porém, quando vou tentar executar o comando:

```
mysql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha_do_usuario' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Ele me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

E se eu tentar o comando:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha';
```

ele retorna o erro:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Estou tentando liberar o acesso ao usuário root, ou mesmo criar um outro usuário para acesso de outras máquinas da rede.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Pare o mysql e reinicie com a opção `--skip-grant-tables`.
2. Conecte ao `mysql` apenas com o comando `mysql` (sem o `-p`, ele não deve pedir usuário)
3. Insira o seguinte comando no client do sql:

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';`

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Depois disso você deve poder usar o comando `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Não consigo acessar o mysql sem o apenas com o comando mysql, ele tenta acessar com o usuário q eu to logado na máquina. Se eu acessar com root e executar esse comando q você passou, funciona será?

Comment: Acredito que sim