# Usuário root sem permissão, mesmo com senha configurada

Tags: mysql

O meu problema se encontra depois de ter instalado o mysql, configurado a senha ( que eu tinha certeza ser do root) e instalar o workbench. 
Quando tento acesso ao banco, diz que:

> Your conncetion attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
>
> ```
> Access denied for user 'root'@localhost'
> ```

Já olhei maneira de conceder acesso, mas o mais [proximo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29671/usu%C3%A1rio-root-mysql-sem-permiss%C3%A3o), o cara ainda consegue inserir a senha. No meu caso, ele não passa.

Usando o SO Ubuntu 18.04
MySql 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

[image: Tentativa de acesso]

Comment: So esqueci de perguntar.
Alguem já viu isso?
Ou mesmo conseguir resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de muito choro e paciência, consegui resolver meu problema.

O lance que trocaram a configuração de senha no momento da instalação e por algum motivo que eu não sei, não aparece mais. Você deve ir atras de configurar isso por você mesmo.

O que eu fiz foi desinstalar tudo, exceto o MySql Workbench (ele não tem nada haver com o problema).

Depois eu instalei tudo de novo, até esse comando:

sudo mysql_secure_installation

Quando eu digitava no terminal

> mysql

Ele dava

> Erro 1045...

Nesse importante momento de raiva, resolvi colocar o

`sudo mysql`

E consegui ter acesso ao MySql.

Dai, você vai ter no terminal o

`mysql>`

Dai você configura usando

`use mysql;`

Depois:

`UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('AsenhaQUEvoceNAOquerMAISesquecer') WHERE User='root';`

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

e por fim:

`exit`

Comment: Esqueci os links que usei para... bom, encontrar a resposta.

https://www.secnet.com.br/blog/alterar-senha-root-mysql-server

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-o-mysql-no-ubuntu-18-04-pt

Answer (score -1):

Só para deixar registrado em caso de perda de senha podemos seguir os passos abaixo para conseguir fazer o reset:

1. Abra e edite `/etc/my.cnf`
2. Adicionar `skip-grant-tables` abaixo de [mysqld]
3. Reinicie o Mysql
4. Você deve poder logar no mysql agora usando o comando: `mysql -u root -p`
5. Executar o comando `mysql> flush privileges;`
6. Definir nova senha por `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';`
7. Volte para `/etc/my.cnf` e remova ou comente `skip-grant-tables`
8. Reinicie o Mysql
9. Agora você poderá fazer o login com a nova senha `mysql -u root -p`

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: Obrigado cara. O problema que eu tentei esse e não deu certo :'(